# google-cloud-vision how to read pdf file

Tags: google-cloud-vision

I am using Google OCR API and I am reading both images and PDF files, I am able to read and process images file, however, for PDF files, as per [Google OCR API documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/pdf), they have mentioned that we need to store our document into Google Cloud service.

Having said that, due to data confidentiality, I can't store my data into Google Cloud and want to upload my PDF from my local system in order to read text from PDF file. Is it possible to upload PDF from local disk and then process it instead of uploading file into Google Cloud?

Comment: I see that you are new to SO, welcome. I proposed an answer, if it solved you issue, consider [accept/upvote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) it so other people who may have the same question can see it works. Again, welcome to SO.

Comment: One of the simple solution is to convert your pdf file into jpg using an online PDF to JPG converter and send that image file instead. You should get the same result as if you were sending a PDF.
I used https://www.ilovepdf.com/pdf_to_jpg to circumvent the same issue I faced.

Answer (score 7):

As you said, it's not possible to do that locally. I filed a Feature Request [[1]](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/113150091) on your behalf for you to follow updates there.

Anyway, I have a possible workaround that might satisfy your data confidentiality awareness. It consist in using the Cloud Storage Client libraries [[2]](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries) to both upload and delete those files:

1. You have the PDF file locally and no buckets containing it.
2. Upload it to a bucket [[3]](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects)
3. Use that bucket+file URI to read it through Cloud Vision API and store the result in a bucket
4. Download the result file into your local machine [[4]](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/downloading-objects)
5. Delete both the PDF file and the result file from the bucket(s) [[5]](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/deleting-objects)

This should work as long as you don't mind having those files in buckets for a brief period of time.

Answer (score 0):

The code for a locally stored file is not under the document specific section, but here: https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/file-small-batch

I summarized the code for both GCP and local options below.

```
# imports
from google.cloud import vision
from google.cloud.vision_v1 import enums
import io

# Set up Vision API
from google.cloud import vision
client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()
features = [{"type": enums.Feature.Type.DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION}]
mime_type = 'application/pdf'

# from GCP
gcs_source_uri = "gs://bk-bucketname/example.pdf"
gcs_source = vision.types.GcsSource(uri=gcs_source_uri)
input_gcp = vision.types.InputConfig(gcs_source=gcs_source, mime_type=mime_type)

# from local
file_path = "./example.pdf"
with io.open(file_path, "rb") as f:
     content = f.read()
input_local = {"mime_type": mime_type, "content": content}

# send the api request
pages = [1] # list of page#s, 5max for online / 2000max for offline/async
requests = [{"input_config": input_local, "features": features, "pages": pages}]
response = client.batch_annotate_files(requests)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may split the PDF onto pages, send them individually to the online OCR API, and merge the results in order. Alternatively, you can rely on an OCR service that can do it for you such as https://base64.ai/demo/document-processing/ocr